# failed to build ffmpeg in vs2019 but can't know why

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to add my ffmpeg to the vs2019(community edition),and here's my step.

1. create an empty c++ program.
   2.go to "ffmpeg-shared file" and copy Folder "include" and "lib" to the root of my c++ program.
   3.copy 8 files of the bin folder to the root of my c++ program.
   4.In vs2019, i added "include" to the additional include directories, also did same thing to lib in linker and add all 8 dll files in the "Linker/input".
   so i wrote a simple program to verify whether it success,but it said that"**unresolved external symbol _avcodec_configuration referenced in function _main"**.  please help.my test code like this:

```
#define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS

extern "C" {
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
}

int main() {
    
    printf("%s", avcodec_configuration());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seriously, it's better to leave installed files where they are and tell your compiler where to find them than to copy files to your project directory. You just end up with multiple copies of libraries and no easy way to update them if you do what you've done.

Comment: Seriously, I know what you mean, but I'm not familiar with vs, I just follow the video and web guide to do that, I just want it to work.

Comment: Well you added include to the 'additional include directories', all you have to do different is to add the original location instead of the copied location. Same for the libraries. Anyway the answer is to link with the lib files not the dll files as said below. You must still be doing something wrong.

Comment: Make sure you aren't mixing 32 bit and 64 bit. If you link 64 bit libraries to a 32 bit program (or vice versa) they will be ignored.

Comment: you are amazing! wow! thanks! i change my program to the x64 than it works!!!!!!!   I'v been solving the problem about two days! thanks a lot,sincerely!

Answer (score 1):

You have to link with the export `.lib` files. Each `ffmpeg` DLL should have a corresponding `.lib` file, which is what should actually go into the linker options. You then have to make sure the DLLs are in the same folder as the output `.exe` binary.

Comment: i put DLLs in the same place with my cpp program, and add "lib" and those "dlls name" in the input of linker options, actually I do exactly as the video said, but just failed

Comment: I've solved it, the problem is my project is created by win32, when I changed it to x64，it worked.thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Well, thanks to john above, I'v solved this problem. Go your project properties and change platform to the x64, then re-configure all build you did before,then it works.